# input top border disappears in windows chrome

Tags: html, css

[code](https://jsfiddle.net/hpa0783m/)

```
<div class="center">
  <div class="parent">
    <label>姓名</label>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</div>


.center {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

.parent {
  padding: 8px 0;
}
label {
  margin-left:  20px;
}
input {
  width: 100px;
  height: 41px;
}
```

I want to know why the top border of the input disappears.I would be appreciated if someone answers me.

os: win10

browser: chrome 51.0.2704.84m

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is occurring because of **transform: translate(-50%, -50%);**

You can modify your css to removing **transform**

```
.center {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
}
.parent {
   padding: 8px 0;
   margin: 15% auto;
   width: 100px;
}
label {
  margin-left:  20px;
}
input {
  width: 100px;
  height: 41px;
}
```

Comment: I want to know why the ``transform`` will influence the border.

Comment: It might be an issue with Chrome, but if you want only border with the existing CSS you can definitely do that just by adding one line of code for border in your input tag:
    border: 1px solid #aaa;

Answer (score 0):

This is a graphical glitch caused by your element being rendered on a sub-pixel by the translation transform (ie: 10.5px or the like).

There are some known solutions to fix this issue, though I haven't had much luck with them:

1) Use `transform: transform: translate(-50%, -50%) perspective(1px);`
2) On the parent element, add.

```
.parent {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

source: http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

If you do not require support for older browsers, you may use flexbox:
https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/